# Right Ctrl release does not work

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My PC runs on win 7 (quad core) with virtual box win xp pro as guest in virtual machine.  The <kbd>right ctrl</kbd> button to release the mouse and keyboard from VM control does not work after I enabled the cd drive and usb ports.  How can I make it work again?

Answer (score -2):

I was having this problem (and Windows 10 crashing when I clicked in the USB section to enable my old Win XP printer). The apparent solution was to reassign the Host key (right ctrl) to something else. I chose F7 and all was well.

I hope that helps you, too.

Changing the host key instructions can be found here: https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2691/virtualbox_change_host_key/