# Keys interpreted by host computer (TeamViewer on Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, remote-control, teamviewer

**What I want to do:** I am trying to remotely control another Windows 8 x64 computer using the latest version of TeamViewer on Ubuntu 13.10 x64. I installed the latest 32-bit version DEB of TeamViewer from the site (x64 didn't work on Ubuntu versions after 12.04 due to depending on the deprecated `ia-lib32` package).

**What happens instead:** The press of some key (combinations) results in effects on both the host and the remote computer. (For example, the <kbd>Super</kbd> key activates both the Start screen on the remote and the Dash on the host.) I would rather have it like VirtualBox where you can choose to send short-cuts or key-presses only to either the host or the virtual computer.

**What I've done:** The *Forward key combinations* option is checked. The effect occurs even when I have been interacting with the remote session window without it having lost focus. I could not find anything relevant using Google.

Comment: Please don't scam helpless (old) people.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing default behavior. See [How to release mouse from VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/579156/how-to-release-mouse-from-virtualbox) . Just recreate a VM with default settings.

When the guest has "focus" then all the keys are sent to the guest only and not to the host. Try disabling mouse and keyboard in the USB section of the config as explained here https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=50865